# yii2 not rendering to view just refreshing the page

Tags: model-view-controller, view, controller, yii2

view.php code part:

```
<a href="/goods/viewgood/<?=$good['GoodGallery'][0]['id']?>" class="btn btn-primary">View Picture</a>
```

viewgood.php

```
<?php
echo 'hello';
```

GoodsController.php

```
 public function viewgood($id = null) {
       
 
   }
```

After clicking on button View Picture my page just refreshing instead of going to viewgood.php
What am I doing incorrectly?
I am a begginer in Yii2

Comment: I don't see where you rendered the view from controller? it's empty. Read the official documentation about rendering views. Action name should be `actionViewgood()` i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
<a href="index.php?r=goods/viewgood/<?=$good['GoodGallery'][0]['id']?>" class="btn btn-primary">View Picture</a>
```

in a anchor  tag html your need use the complete route, for use shortcut you try use

```
<?= Html::a('View Picture', ['/goods/viewgood/', 'id' => $good['GoodGallery'][0]['id']], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**view.php**

You can use Html:a(), or in your example use Url helper to() function to generate the proper route for your anchor tag.

```
<a href="<?=Url::to(['/goods/viewgood', 'id' => $good['GoodGallery'][0]['id']] ); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">View Picture</a>
```

**GoodsController.php**

```
public function actionViewgood($id=null){
  //fetch the data e.g.
  $model = Good::findOne(id); 

 //Do some extra code checking when no record is found like throw an exception or set a flash error message, etc.

 //render the viewgood and pass the data (if needed)
  return $this->render('viewgood', [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```

**viewgood.php**

```
<?php
    //do what you want with the data passed by the controller. E.g. print the name of the good (if applicable)
    echo $model->name;

    //your other code ...
?>
```